# how to check if the value is integer or string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, text

how can i check if a value in a list is integer or string and get True if its integer

```
list = ["1 asd","sw asdd34","2asdas"]
```

how can i check if the value start with integer and get back `True` or `False`.

i have tried:

```
        for i in range(1, len(array)):

        print("".join(array[i][:2]))
        try:
            if (int("".join(array[i][:4])) % 2 != 0):
                top_row.insert(i,array[i])
                print("port {} have been added on 
        top_row".format(array[i]))
            elif (int("".join(array[i][:4])) % 2 == 0):
                down_row.insert(i,array[i])
                print("port {} have been added on 
           down_row".format(array[i]))
            elif (int("".join(array[i][:4])) is not 
         (isinstance("".join(array[i][:4]), int))):
                top_row.insert(i,"NONE")
                print("add a none ")


            else:
                down_row.append(None)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: it should add all the number that started with 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 to a list name top row and the dupple to the down list

Answer (score 2):

A pretty pythonic and actually pretty fast way to do it is just to try it.

```py
a = someintorstring

try:
    int(a)
    # it's an int
except ValueError:
    # not an int
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to start with an integer? Try a regex:

```
import re

for elem in your_list:
    if re.match(r'^[0-9]+', elem):
        # element starts with an integer, do your thing
```